# Como forçar download de arquivos de Vídeo online UOL

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber forçar o download de arquivos nesse tipo de URL

```
http://videohd7.mais.uol.com.br/15529034.mp4?p=1&r=http%3A%2F%2Fmais.uol.com.br
```

já usei um código que realiza isso com tudo o download foi danificado o arquivo ficou com 1kbs e não efetua o download direito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O arquivo não foi danificado, se você abrir o arquivo baixado vai notar que ao invés de dados binários haverá uma mensagem, provavelmente HTML com algum detalhe de erro, isto ocorre por que você não passou o user-agent e outros headers necessários.

> Nota: Sobre baixar vídeos destes servidores, eu pessoalmente não sei como funciona as questões de direitos autorais, só postei a resposta pois pode ser um sistema de vídeos pessoais, ou coisas do gênero a responsabilidade do conteúdo baixado é de como será desenvolvido a aplicação.

Usando `curl` faça algo como (para salvar o vídeo no seu servidor):

```
$url = 'http://videohd7.mais.uol.com.br/15529034.mp4?p=1&r=http%3A%2F%2Fmais.uol.com.br';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

//Envia o user-agent do usuário para o dominio
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

//Também pode adicionar como conexão fechada, alguns servidores bloqueiam se não ouver o header Connection
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Connection: close'
));

$data = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($ch);

if ($httpcode !== 206 && $httpcode !== 200) {
    echo 'Erro http:', $httpcode;
} else {
   file_put_contents('arquivo.mp4', $data, FILE_BINARY);//A flag FILE_BINARY é necessária
}
```

Se o download for direto para o cliente (forçar o download no navegador), use:

```
curl_close($ch);

if ($httpcode !== 206 && $httpcode !== 200) {
    echo 'Erro http:', $httpcode;
} else {
    header('Content-type: video/mp4');
    header('Content-length: ' . strlen($data)); //Seta o tamanho do arquivo
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=arquivo.mp4');//Força o download
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); //Este header é necessário

    echo $data;
}
```

Comment: Só uma divida no caso onde esta http:// seria a url certo e onde esta no caso arquivo.mp4 seria ele renomeado certo ?

Comment: no caso ele pegaria em http:// seria aquela url que coloquei da uol passaria pra forçar o download e no final onde a arquivo.php seria o arquivo com novo nome ou o mesmo se assim eu quiser ne.

Comment: @Rodrigo editei a resposta.