# Baixar arquivo para o servidor

Tags: php, arquivo, download

Eu possuo a URL de onde o arquivo é baixado. Ao clicar nela, o arquivo é baixado diretamente, sem ao menos acessar e clicar em algum link.

Dito isso preciso de uma forma de automatizar essa tarefa com PHP. Um script que quando executado baixe esse arquivo para determinada pasta no servidor a cada X minutos. Alguma sugestão?

O arquivo está em formato .csv.

Destaco ainda que por ser uma hospedagem contratada(Hostinger, Locaweb, etc...) não tenho acesso full.

O problema principal seria o script para download.

Comment: Isto deve lhe ajudar http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/73084/3635

Answer (score 0):

Procura por tarefas crons, serve pra scripts php....

```
0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /seuarquivophp.php
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, mas não é exatamente esse o principal problema. Editei a pergunta de forma a ficar mais clara.